# motempl.c: cvCalcGlobalOrientation always get 0 angle in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu

I am doing a project which involve the motempl.c in opencv, which I use it to detect the motion and direction of the moving objects.

However, one weird thing happened as the motempl.c is running flawlessly in window (I use window studio 2010), but when I run it in linux platform, everything seems normal, except the angle which displayed in the small red and the big white circles always zero.

I compare the codes between the Window and the Ubuntu, and they are the same.

So, after I am checking again, I am suspecting this is caused by the cvCalGlobalOrientation function in opencv.

Can anyone please give some advice about this?

Really appreciate)

Comment: Hi, actually the code is available in the sample folder of opencv (opencv249\sources\samples\c\motempl.c), The codes are as below:

Comment: since the codes are too long, I will just copy part of it, as below:

Comment: // calculate orientation
        angle = cvCalcGlobalOrientation( orient, mask, mhi, timestamp, MHI_DURATION);
        angle = 360.0 - angle;  // adjust for images with top-left origin

Comment: troubleshooting until now still have no clue....honestly, my programming is really weak....just now I attempt to merge the codes of the cvCalcGlobalOrientation (from:https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/optflow/src/motempl.cpp)  into the update_mhi part of the motempl.c codes, since I suspect the function of cvCalGlobalOrientation might not function properly in Linux,  but due to the different type of classes used, ends up even more errors....

Comment: any suggestion is really appreciated)

Comment: So, is there anyone having the same/similar problem when using the opencv function of cvCalcGlobalOrientation in linux, which always return zero, for the angle value?  please help....thank you so much.